# Is there a way to escape keywords in kwargs

Tags: python

I have the following instance function

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.request = dict()

    def my_func(self, **kwargs):
        self.request['arguments'] = kwargs
```

And I wish to use it as below:

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.my_func(global = True)
```

As you can see, I wish to use a Python keyword as a key value on the `kwargs`. I know it is a syntax error. I wonder if there is a way to escape it so one can produce a `kwargs` with value `{'global':True}`.

I couldn't find anything related to this in the official docs. I was expecting a way to escape them as `kwargs` keys are of type `string`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's going to be part of public API for a network messaging protocol so I was expecting a nice-looking solution to pass optional arguments to a request message/object. That's one solution though, thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Any reason to post that as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: why not just add the optional args in the init method defaulting to False?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, `MyClass` is a simplistic example. The case is that I have a message factory that creates Python `dict` objects given some parameters. Some of those are predefined, others are optional and not predefined. I cannot know beforehand which parameter names can be used as optional parameters. `global` is one such optional parameter example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you can use Python keywords as keyword-argument names is by unpacking a dictionary:

```
instance.my_func(**{'global': True})
```

Alternatively, rename the argument (to e.g. `global_`).